# Wordpress Custom PHP failing at wpdb object

Tags: php, forms, web, wordpress

I am trying to create a form on wordpress that automatically updates a custom table in the database. The form works with the "POST" method and calls the PHP file fine, and any code (such as echos) I enter at the beginning work fine. The problem is every time I try and use the wpdb object, the screen is just white and the code stops. It won't run anything including or past where I call wpdb. I have tried both using insert and get results and neither is working. Also, I am getting absolutely *no errors* in the console output even though I turned debugging on and everything.

This is my php file (which has a permission value of 755):

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        echo "New Plant has been submitted.\n";

        $plantname = $_POST["name"];
        echo "Before";
        $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users" );
        exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
        echo " After: " . $myrows;
        $wpdb->insert('Plants',array('PlantName' => $plantname),array('%s'));
        echo $plantname . " has been submitted.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, this is my form:

```
&nbsp;

<form action="cgi-bin/add_plant.php" method="post">
Plant Name: <input name="name" type="text" />

Lowest Ideal Temperature: <input name="IdealTempLow" type="text" />

Highest Ideal Temperature: <input name="IdealTempHigh" type="text" />

Lowest Ideal pH: <input name="IdealpHLow" type="text" />

Highest Ideal pH: <input name="IdealpHHigh" type="text" />

Lowest Ideal Humidity Level: <input name="IdealHumLow" type="text" />

Highest Ideal Humidity Level: <input name="IdealHumHigh" type="text" />

Lowest Ideal Moisture Level: <input name="IdealMoistLow" type="text" />

Highest Ideal Moisture Level: <input name="IdealMoistHigh" type="text" />

<input type="submit" />
</form>&nbsp;
```

By the way, I know I need to sanitize my code, but for right now I just want to be able to get it to work in the first place. I know that nothing is getting added because I logged in to PHPMyAdmin and there is nothing in the table. I also tried getting results from the standard wp tables, but that failed as well.

**Edit 1**

I have moved everything into a custom template file. I had gotten it working with the separate php file, but I moved it so that I could do form validation and everything all without switching pages. However, now I am having the same error. I had used "require_once" to include wp-load.php in the original and it worked, however now wpdb is still failing and I can't figure out how to include wp-load without it also failing. Originally loading up the page works: I can submit the form however on submit the page fails.

```
<?php
    require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-config.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php');
?>
<?php global $asteria;?>

<?php 
    get_header();
?>

<?php global $wpdb;?>

<?php
    function test_input($data) 
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    function selfURL()
    {
        $ret = substr(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),0,strpos( strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL' ]), "/") );
        $ret .= ( empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? NULL : ( ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "s" : NULL) );
        $ret .= "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $ret .= ( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? "" : ":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ); 
        $ret .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        return $ret;
    }

    function submitPlant($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i)
    {
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        // $wpdb->replace('Plants',
        //  array(
        //      'PlantName' => $a,
        //      'IdealTempLow' => $b,
        //      'IdealTempHigh' => $c,
        //      'IdealPHLow' => $d,
        //      'IdealPHHigh' => $e,
        //      'IdealHumidityLow' => $f,
        //      'IdealHumidityHigh' => $g,
        //      'IdealMoistureLow' => $h,
        //      'IdealMoistureHigh' => $i
        //      ),
        //  array(
        //      '%s',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f',
        //      '%f'
        //      )
        //  );
        // $a = $wpdb->insert_id;
        // if ($a == false) {
        //  $SubmitMsg = "Plant entry failed. Please contact system admin.";
        //  echo "Error: " . $wpdb->print_error();
        // } else {
            $SubmitMsg = "New Plant has been submitted.";
        // }
        return $SubmitMsg;
    }

... Validation Functions...
?>

<?php
$PlantName = $IdealTempLow = $IdealTempHigh = $IdealpHLow = $IdealpHHigh = $IdealHumLow = $IdealHumHigh = $IdealMoistLow = $IdealMoistHigh = "";

$NameErr = $LTempErr = $HTempErr = $LpHErr = $HpHErr = $LHumErr = $HHumErr = $LMoistErr = $HMoistErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $SubmitMsg = "";

...Form Validation...

    if (($NameErr == "") && ($LTempErr == "") && ($HTempErr == "") && ($LpHErr == "") && ($HpHErr == "") && ($LHumErr == "") && ($HHumErr == "") && ($LMoistErr == "") && ($HMoistErr == ""))
    {
        $SubmitMsg = submitPlant($PlantName, $IdealTempLow, $IdealTempHigh, $IdealpHLow, $IdealpHHigh, $IdealHumLow, $IdealHumHigh, $IdealMoistLow, $IdealMoistHigh);
    }

}
?>

<!--Content-->
<div class="fixed_site">
    <div class="fixed_wrap singlefx">
        <?php if(($asteria['page_type_id']) == '1'){ ?>
            <div class="page_tt">
                <div class="center"><h1 class="postitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
            </div> 
        <?php } ?>

<div id="content">
<div class="center">
<div class="single_wrap no_sidebar">
<div class="single_post">
    <?php if(have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()): ?><?php the_post(); ?>
            <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">  

                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() ) { ?><div class="edit_wrap"><a href="<?php echo get_edit_post_link( ); ?>"><i title="<?php _e('Edit This','asteria'); ?>" class="fa-edit"></i></a></div><?php } ?>

                    <div class="single_post_content">
                        <?php if(($asteria['page_type_id']) == '2'){ ?><h1 class="postitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1><?php } ?>
                            <div class="thn_post_wrap"><?php the_content(); ?> </div> 
                            <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="thn_post_wrap"><?php wp_link_pages('<p class="pages"><strong>'.__('Pages:').'</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile ?> 
</div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <span style="color:blue"><?php echo $SubmitMsg;?></span>
    <form action="<?php echo selfURL(); ?>" method="POST">

    Plant Name: <input name="PlantName" type="text" value="<?php echo $PlantName;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $NameErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Lowest Ideal Temperature: <input name="IdealTempLow" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealTempLow;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $LTempErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Highest Ideal Temperature: <input name="IdealTempHigh" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealTempHigh;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $HTempErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Lowest Ideal pH: <input name="IdealpHLow" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealpHLow;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $LpHErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Highest Ideal pH: <input name="IdealpHHigh" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealpHHigh;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $HpHErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Lowest Ideal Humidity Level: <input name="IdealHumLow" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealHumLow;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $LHumErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Highest Ideal Humidity Level: <input name="IdealHumHigh" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealHumHigh;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $HHumErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Lowest Ideal Moisture Level: <input name="IdealMoistLow" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealMoistLow;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $LMoistErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    Highest Ideal Moisture Level: <input name="IdealMoistHigh" type="text" value="<?php echo $IdealMoistHigh;?>"/><span style="color:red"> * <?php echo $HMoistErr;?></span>
    </br><div height="5">&nbsp;</div>

    <input type="submit" name="submitted"/>
    </form>

</div>

<!--PAGE END-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you must have php errors off. $wpdb is not available in a standalone php page unless you include wp-load. You can of course use mysqli instead.

Comment: Thanks. Now the code doesn't fail and doesn't give any errors, but it just isn't updating the table.

Comment: are you using the same code or have you made changes? There is an exit in the above code.

Comment: I updated the code so that it all runs in a custom theme template for a specific page so that I could do form validation and keep everything on the same page. I had gotten it to work with the separate page, however now it doesn't want to work this way.